# Visual Studio Debugger - Unable To Attach. Operation Timed Out

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I started to get this error when trying to run my CordovaApp in Debug Mode:  `Unable to attach.Operation timed out.` First i was getting it quite often but still sometimes it was able to attach and now i'm always getting it.

[image]

The application is deployed and started successfully in the emulator or on my Android Device.

How can I solve this? Is it possible to increase timeout threshold? (maybe if I wait more it can attach as sometimes it was working before).

EDIT:

Reproducible on 3 different machines.

Comment: Can you try following 1.) uninstall the app from device or emulator 2.) Restart the Visual Studio and if it does not fix, restart device and machine.

Comment: hi, after restart it worked only once and then the issue reappeared.

Comment: Did you tried restarting the machine?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, 
find some workaround that works for me without restarting. 
all is done in emulator UI

1. in the emulator -> apps (show all apps installed including yours that refuse to run)
2. side bar -> click "menu" and select "Manage Apps"
3. scroll down to your app
4. click "clear data" and "force stop"
5. go back to apps and click on your app.
6. cross your fingers and wait few seconds ..

hope it's helps