# An error occurred trying to attach to the Google Android Emulator. Exception: Unable to attach. Operation timed out

Tags: android, visual-studio, ionic2, visual-studio-cordova

This Question is Not a Dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516456/visual-studio-debugger-unable-to-attach-operation-timed-out) one . because it doesn't have a accepted answer.

I have added the following in my Config.xml and tried to debug in device but it failed to start debugging

```
  <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="60000" />
```

**Update:**

I have created a New project (but not with my existing code) and it is able to debug. In my current old Project these are the plugins i have installed

1. One-Signal
2. Cordova-Plugin-console
3. Network Information
4. Splash Screen
5. status bar
6. streaming
7. ionic-keyboard-plugin